# How to select first item in MS Access combobox if form is unbound

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I tried to preselect the first item in my combobox item with:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.ProjectBox = Me.ProjectBox.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```

but it says ItemData(0) is null. I think this is because it is being run before the query(Row Source property) to populate the combobox. Is there a way to run it after the combobox is populated

Comment: I just tried the same code with an unbound ComboBox on one of my forms and it worked perfectly, so at least in my case the RowSource query has been executed and the results have already populated the ComboBox's list.  You should consider when and how the RowSource is being specified.  Is it being set in the designer or the Form_Open() event so that the query is available during the Form_Load() event handler?

Comment: How many columns does the *RowSource* query have and what values are set for the *ColumnCount* and *BoundColumn* properties?  Also the *ColumnWidths* (with an 's') property?  The ItemData collection returns not necessarily the displayed value, rather the bound value. (Even if the control is "unbound", meaning that there is no field specified for the form's data, the term *bound* is also used to indicate which column of the RowSource query will be returned by the ComboBox.Value property and the ItemData collection.)  Post the values of all ComboBox properties I mentioned for further assistance.

Comment: ColumnCount:2, Column Widths: 0";1", BoundColumn:0.  I also tried to used it in Form_Load() but had more errors because nothing else on the form had been loaded yet. I also had already tried requery but that does nothing different for me. One thing I forgot to mention is that when I run Me.ProjectBox = Me.ProjectBox.ItemData(0) in Form_Load() it prevents the ComboBox from populating any entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code should work fine...

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.ProjectBox = Me.ProjectBox.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```

if ComboBox properties are set correctly in the designer Property Sheet, for example:

```
RowSource = {query}
ColumnCount = 2     
BoundColumn = 1   
ColumnWidths = 0";1"
```

Specifically notice that **BoundColumn = 1**.

See [online docs for BoundColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.boundcolumn).  `BoundColumn = 0` has a special meaning, namely that the ComboBox's value becomes the list index value (0, 1, 2...) rather than the value of a RowSource column.  Note that the index values for other properties like `ComboBox.Column(index, row)` are 0-based, while `ComboBox.BoundColumn` starts at 1 for the first RowSource column... a frustrating inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

You could requery the combobox. That will pause the code until done:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.ProjectBox.Requery
    Me.ProjectBox = Me.ProjectBox.ItemData(0)
End Sub
```